# Custom Language Model using Python3, Openai

Tags: model, openai-api, chatgpt-api

https://medium.com/@sohaibshaheen/train-chatgpt-with-custom-data-and-create-your-own-chat-bot-using-macos-fb78c2f9646d

I was using this tutorial to create my language model. I overlooked the UPDATE notice on the bottom on my first run, so I ran into the error that got.index cant be found. Now I updated the code and used the llama.index instead with my secret key. Now my problem is that when I try to run the "Python3 app.py" command I get the "can't open file '/Users/*my-Name*/app.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory" error. I tried installing the Docs folder and the app.py (created with textedit in MacOS) into the Users directory but then I get the "Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/*my.-Name*/app.py", line 1, in 
from llama_index import SimpleDirectoryReader, GPTSimpleVectorIndex, LLMPredictor, ServiceContext
ImportError: cannot import name 'GPTSimpleVectorIndex' from 'llama_index' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/llama_index/**init**.py)" error.

I want to know what I did wrong or why it failed even when I installed it directly in the User directory